# how 2 same valued spinners depend on each other selection of one spinner hide that value in second spinner

Tags: java, android, xml

I am working on an Android bus reservation App, and I have to make two spinners that have the same values e.g. cities names. One spinner is to select your source city and second spinner is for destination city.

Help me how to manage these two spinners like selecting one item(city name) in first spinner hides that item in second spinner.

Comment: you just have to remove that position value from adapter

Comment: if you want to hide then you have to make custom adapter and have to write some logic for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did for my listView...this should also work for spinner I have modified it a bit for spinner

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,yourArray);

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, yourArray);

arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

arrayAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        //remove the selected item from other adapter
        arrayAdapter2.remove(arrayAdapter.getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
});
```

Same can be done with other adapter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Remove that particular position item then you can do like below:

```
object t=m_adapterForSpinner.getitem(pos);//whr m_arrayadapter is array adapter using for filling spinner
```

then remove item from adapter like this

```
m_adapterForSpinner.remove((CharSequence) t);
```

then fill again spinner with adapter.

Now if you want to hide particular position item then you can do like this.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

 private int hidingItemIndex;

 public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects, int hidingItemIndex) {
     super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
     this.hidingItemIndex = hidingItemIndex;
 }

 @Override
 public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     View v = null;
     if (position == hidingItemIndex) {
         TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
         tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         v = tv;
     } else {
         v = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
     }
     return v;
 }
 }
```

Use like below:

```
int hidingItemIndex = 0;

CustomAdapter dataAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list, hidingItemIndex);

dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mySpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```